# "The file cannot be downloaded" when i download passbook from home screen webapp

Tags: web-applications, ios6, iphone-web-app, passbook

i could download file via *mobile safari browser* with an `<a>` link. But when i saved my website as an *home screen app*, then i can not download the `.pkpass`(passbook file). And i got this warning:

```
The file cannot be downloaded!
```

Then i checked the request, i found the user agent is different:

**safari browser:**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25
```

**home screen inner browser**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e
```

Yes, there's no `safari` suffix in the request from *home screen app*

Is this IOS6's bug?

Comment: Do you send the required header `Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass`? It might force the file to open properly.

Comment: @MikulasDite yes, i have add that mimetype

Comment: I'm still having this issue with iOS 8. This is a rather annoying bug. I should be able to download a passbook file from within a home screen webapp - and not send the user to a page in safari.

Answer (score 0):

The UIWebViewController class does not do what Mobile Safari does with passes or downloaded files in general. I think, but do not know for sure, that those home screen apps use that controller and so have the same limitations.

Comment: So, maybe the UIWebViewController class's limitation